# HelloComponent is not part of NgModule even though it's listed in the entry components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've [created a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-injector?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) where I'm trying to instantiate the `HelloComponent` dynamically using the `ReflexiveInjector` and I have the `HelloComponent` listed in the app modules `entryComponents` array.

However I'm still getting:

> Component HelloComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

Thoughts?

[Added a link to this SO in this feature request asking for virtual / logical modules](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29007).  Please thumbs it up if you like the suggestion.

Comment: you should add it to declarations too.

Comment: HelloComponent should be a part of your declarations as well.

Comment: Add HelloComponent to your declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ]

Comment: Yes your component needs to be declared and your forked stackblitz with solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-injector-tfggss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also declare the `HelloComponent` in your declarations array of your module. [Read the official docs about entrycomponents](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-an-entry-component).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  entryComponents: [HelloComponent],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ], // declare here
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```